# Perl: method write, write_string are not working

Tags: excel, perl

Below is my code:

```
use Spreadsheet::WriteExcel;
my @worksheet ;
my($server_count) = 0;
my($row) = 0;
$worksheet[$server_count] = $workbook->addworksheet("Break Summary");

$worksheet[$server_count]->set_column(0, 0, 60);
$worksheet[$server_count]->set_column(1, 1, 20);

$worksheet[$server_count]->write_string($row, 0, "PositionsSTB" ,$summary_title_format);
$worksheet[$server_count]->write_string(++$row, 0, "Number of distinct accounts breaking" ,$general_format);
&log_info ("\nPOS 0 $break_summary_excel_results[0]");
$worksheet[$server_count]->write_number($row, 1, $break_summary_excel_results[0] ,$general_format);
```

It print information to log, but not into Excel.

Comment: Is that actually your code? It will give an error because you never assigned anything to $workbook

Comment: No, I have it: my $workbook  = Spreadsheet::WriteExcel->new($gloss_audit.$file_name);

Answer (score 2):

Your code actually works for me (with slight change about "$format" variables not defined in your sample). Here is my whole test file:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use Spreadsheet::WriteExcel;

my @worksheet;
my $server_count = 0;
my $row = 0;

my $workbook = Spreadsheet::WriteExcel->new('excel_file.xls');

my $format = $workbook->add_format();
$format->set_bold();
$format->set_color('red');
$format->set_align('center');

$worksheet[$server_count] = $workbook->addworksheet("Break Summary");

$worksheet[$server_count]->set_column(0, 0, 60);
$worksheet[$server_count]->set_column(1, 1, 20);

$worksheet[$server_count]->write_string($row, 0, "PositionsSTB" ,$format);
$worksheet[$server_count]->write_string(++$row, 0, "Number of distinct accounts breaking");
$worksheet[$server_count]->write_number($row, 1, $break_summary_excel_results[0] ,$general_format);
```

I use Spreadsheet::WriteExcel version 2.37 on linux. In my case the output from the code above is Excel file "excel_file.xls" of length 5632 bytes with 1 worksheet ("Break Summary") and 3 cells:

A1: "PositionsSTB" (centered, red, bold)
A2: "Number of distinct accounts breaking" (no specjal formatting)
B2: 0 (no specjal formatting)

Maybe you shoule add `$workbook->close;` at the end of your code?

Hope it helps.